# Can't reset -webkit-filter: in inner div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue with  -webkit-filter property. I have div which displays background image and inside it another div which is containter for icon, logo and heading text.

Background image class:

```
.image-bg-fluid-height,


.image-bg-fixed-height {

     -webkit-filter:brightness(50%);
    -moz-filter:brightness(50%);
    filter: url(#brightness); /* required for FF */
    filter:brightness(50%);
}

.image-bg-fixed-height {
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;

}

.image-bg-fluid-height {
    background: url('../images/header.png') no-repeat center center scroll;
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.image-bg-fixed-height {
    background: url('../images/header.png') no-repeat center center scroll;
    height: 80%;
}
```

Inside div class:

```
.overlay-layer{
    -webkit-filter: initial;
    filter: initial;  

}
```

and HTML:

```
     <header class="image-bg-fluid-height ">
        <div class="containter">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="overlay-layer">
                <img class="img-responsive img-center" src="images/logo-2.png" alt="">
[...]
```

Unfortunately whatever content is inside "overlay-layer" is also affected by webkit-filter (50% brightness etc.) and I can't reset it. I also tried set it to 100% but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the way it works. Resetting a filter on an element inside another element that has a filter on it will  not reset the filter of the parent element.

Comment: @Rvervuurt right next to your name--by your comment, there's little edit and delete buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Filtering options (and other styling properties like for example opacity) affect the element *and* everything inside it.

The only (poor) option is to make a div that overlays the `.image-bg-fixed-height` element.

Comment: Any other idea how to create dimmed background image to not affect inside div?

Comment: could you tell more about that? Of course I can dimm file in photoshop, but I would rather do it dynamically.

Comment: Yes, see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ekvbmhft/. You'll need to place an overlay absolute, an make it fill up the other div. I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

That isn't solution for original issue (reset webkit-filter), but I solved my original issue (dimmed background image without affecting inside content) with this code:

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('../images/header.png') no-repeat center center scroll;
```

Question was also already answered by Ted, unfortunately it is impossible.